# How to remove quotes from Numeric data in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have one numeric feature in a data frame but in excel some of the values contain quotes which need to be removed.

Below table is what my data appears to be in Excel file now I want to remove quotes from last 3 rows using python.

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | A |
| 456 | B |
| 789 | C |
| "123" | D |
| "456" | E |
| "789" | F |

I have used following code in Python:

```
df["Col1"] = df['Col1'].replace('"', ' ').astype(int)
```

But above code gives me error message: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '"123"'.

I have also tried strip() function but still it is not working.

If I do not convert the data type and use below code

```
df["Col1"] = df['Col1'].replace('"', ' ')
```

Then the code is getting executed without any error however while saving the file into CSV it is still showing quotes.

Comment: Do you really need to parse it as an integer? If the only thing you need is to make a CSV out of this data, you don't really need to get it as integer. Also, try using `replace` with an empty string, not a blank space. `df["Col1"] = df['Col1'].replace('"', '')`

Comment: Hello Luka, I have tried both the approach but still it doesn't work

Comment: @Data-7scientist, what is your DF type , if you do `df.dtypes` ? To get the right solution you need to look at the data at the first place if you can parse or manipulate at the outfit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use converter function while reading Excel file. Something along those lines (assuming that data provided is in Excel file in columns 'A' and 'B'):

```
import pandas as pd

def conversion(value):
    if type(value) == int:
        return value
    else:
        return value.strip('"')

df = pd.read_excel('remove_quotes_excel.xlsx', header=None,
                   converters={0: conversion})

# df
     0  1
0  123  A
1  456  B
2  789  C
3  123  D
4  456  E
5  789  F
```

Both columns are object type, but now (if needed) it is straightforward to convert to int:

```
df[0] = df[0].astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using this code. (Regex is if you get a warning)

```
df.Col1.replace('\"', '', regex = True, inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert the Col1 into series

```
df_Series = df['Col1']
```

Apply replace function on series

```
df_Series = df_Series.replace('"','').astype(int)
```

then append the Series into df data frame.